# SELECT column based on conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a table similar to the following:

```
+---------+--------------+
| user_id | distance     |
+---------+--------------+
|     101 | 12.05        |
|     103 | 4.8          |
|     207 | 37.1         |
|     991 | 3.51         |
|     215 | 15.9         |
+---------+--------------+
```

Then I want the number of users that cover different range of distances: `0-5km` as `short_distance`, `5-10km` as `medium_distance`, `>10km` as `long_distance`.

I'm kind of confused when aggregating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the count of users category wise. Try This

```
select 
       case 
         when distance > 10 then 'long_distance'
         when distance > 5  then 'medium_distance'
         else 'short_distance'
      end as "distance_type", count(*) as "Count"
from user_distance

group by "distance_type"
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5DmJSXS8gYVHVFHkV8MC7Z/1)

Comment: @thank you. Is there a way I can count this is I now, say 100 users cover <5, 40 cover 2-10 etc. That would help towards my analysis.

Comment: Do you want something like this [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5DmJSXS8gYVHVFHkV8MC7Z/2)

Answer (score 2):

use a CASE expression:

```
select user_id, 
       case 
         when distance <= 5 then 'short distance'
         when distance <= 10 then 'medium distance'
         else 'long distance'
       end as what
from the_table;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. I get confused with aggregation.